# Vertical align text in bootstrap list-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to `vertical-align` the text and button in a `list-group-item` with bootstrap 3. I've tried to make the parent `a` to have `display: table;` and the inner divs a `display: table-cell;` so that I can use `vertical-align: middle`.

But the above won't fix it, here's a **[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqmQxe)** I've created that reproduces the problem.

Although for some reason if I post the same code here in SO snippet it seems to be working. However, when I render that in my HTML document it won't work.

```css
a {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table;
}

a > div {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
}

.btn {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="list-group">
    <!-- ngRepeat: value in results -->
    <a href="/store/products/testing" class="list-group-item search-product ng-scope" ng-repeat="value in results">
      <div class="media col-md-3">
        <figure class="pull-left">
          <img class="media-object img-rounded img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500" alt="Testing">
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading ng-binding"> Test product </h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text ng-binding" ng-bind-html="value.short_description | to_trusted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et…</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
        <div ng-controller="postDataToCartCtrl" class="ng-scope">
          <form url="store/addtocart" ng-submit="add(value.id, 1)" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
            <input name="quantity" type="hidden" value="1">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add to Cart
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: value in results -->

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have modified your CSS code a bit

**CSS**

```
a.list-group-item {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table;
}

a.list-group-item > div {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  float:none;
}
```

checkout above code. instead of `a {}` I have used `a.list-group-item {}` as default bootstrap `.list-group-item {}` class was overwriting `display:table` properties.

Comment: This works, but when I did it, it made my list-group-items shorter. Not sure how to get the length back.

Comment: @JacobBeauchamp I am not sure why you are facing this width issue. But if you can create a codepen or something, then I can help you with the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the floats, on the divs, i.e. like this:

```
a > div {
 float: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, although its better to avoid `!important` declarations! Maybe having a higher specificity value.